# Sequential criterion for functional limits proof in the opposite direction

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

Let $f: A\to\mathbb{R}$ Given $c$ is a cluster point in $A$. Prove that the following statements are equivalent:
(a) The function $f$ does not have a limit at $c$.
(b) There exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $A$ with $x_n \neq c$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to $c$ but the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ does not converge in $\mathbb{R}$

My attempt:
Assume $f$ has no limit at $c$, $x_n$ is a sequence in $A$, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}x_n =c$ ie  $\mid x_n-c\mid<\delta$ , WTS $f(x_n)$ does not converge.

If $f(x_n)$ is not bounded, clearly $f(x_n)$ does not converge in $\mathbb{R}$

Otherwise pick a convergent subsequence of $f(x_n)$ let  $L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)$ since $\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x_n)$ does not exist the negation of the definition of a limit says: there exist $\epsilon>0$ such that there is $x \in$  $A\backslash {c}$ with $\mid f(x)-L\mid>\epsilon$

QED

My concern is that the proof is too short and kinda repeats what is given in the question

Comment: Hi, I edited your question so that it is a bit easier to read. Please check if I accidentally alter the meaning of your question.

Comment: Can you also include the definition of $f$ having a limit at $c$?

Comment: Thanks for the editing! f(x) has limit at c i.e, $\mid f(x)-L\mid<\epsilon$ for $\mid x_n-c\mid <\delta$

Comment: Is the following your definition: Given a function $f:A \to \mathbb R$ and $c$ a cluster point of $A$, we write $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = L$ if: for all $\epsilon >0$ there is $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x) - L| <\epsilon$ whenever $|x-c| < \delta$?

Comment: yes, thanks for correcting me

Comment: This question is not that easy and a rigorous proof is actually I bit long......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give you some hints in proving the equivalence of $(a)$ and $(b)$. This is not an easy question if you are new to the subject. First of all, note that it suffices to show that the negation of both statements are equivalent: that is:

(a') $f$ has a limit at $c$, and

(b') For all $\{x_n\}$ in $A$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = c$, the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ converges.

$(a') \Rightarrow (b')$ is easier: Assume $(a')$ is true. That is, by definition, there is $L$ so that:

(*) For all $\epsilon >0$, there is $\delta >0$ so that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ whenever $x\in A$ and $|x-c| < \delta$.

Now let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $A$ converging to $c$. Then for all $\delta >0$, there is $N_\delta \in \mathbb N$ so that $|x_n - c|< \delta$ whenever $n \geq N_\delta$. Try to use this and (*) to show

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n) = L.$$

For $(b') \Rightarrow (a')$, you might try to proof the following two facts: Assuming $(b')$, then

(i) For any $\{x_n\}$ in $A$ and $lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = c$, the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ converges to the same real number $L$ (independent of sequence $\{x_n\}$ chosen.

(ii) Use (i) to show that $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = L$.

For both (i) and (ii), it will be easier to argue by contradiction.

Comment: I have a question about this part: 'Now let {x_n} be a sequence in A converging to c.' How do we know that a sequence like this always exists?

Comment: This can be answered in two ways: (i) We are showing that "for all sequence $\{x_n\}$ converging to $c$, we have ......". To show this, I don't need to know if there is really such a sequence (if there is not such a sequence, our statement is trivially true). or (ii) since $c$ is a cluster point of $A$, then for any $\epsilon >0$, there is $a \in A\setminus\{c\}$ and $|a-c|<\epsilon$. Now take $\epsilon = 1/n$, then for each $n$ there is $x_n\in A$ so that $|x_n - c|< 1/n$. This sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to $c$. @user394691